# How do I create a new git repository from a folder in an existing git repository?

Tags: git, version-control

I want to create a new git repository of a folder under an existing git repository. I want the history to be preserved in the new repository. How do I create this new git repository?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can clone it, and then apply on the clone a filter-branch in order to **split that repository**, extracting only the directory you want (with its full history).

See [Detach subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository)

Note the `git clone --no-hardlinks /XYZ /ABC` used during the cloning step:

> The `--no-hardlinks` switch makes git use real file copies instead of hardlinking when cloning a local repository.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you only want to keep the subdirectory as a separate project: you can use `git filter-branch` for that.

1. Create a new branch
2. Define a "tree filter" that rearranges a checked out copy the way you want, ideally as a separate script
3. Run `git filter-branch --tree-filter=/path/to/script thebranch`

You now have a separate branch that is not related to the normal development stream, containing just the subdirectory. Whoever clones the new branch gets only the subproject history.

Comment: You don't need to define a (custom) tree filter here. The built-in subdirectory filter does exactly this, as described in the answer linked to in [VonC's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421386/how-do-i-create-a-new-git-repository-from-a-folder-in-an-existing-git-repository/5421581#5421581). You also don't want to do this on a new branch in the same repo, but rather in separate clone. If a repo contained both the subdirectory and full project on separate branches, an initial clone would fetch both, creating remote tracking branches for each. Wasteful!

Answer (score -2):

You can clone it and keep the files you want; history will then be preserved.